# Change mysql user password using command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, putty

I'm trying to update the password for a database user using the command line, and it's not working for me. This is the code I'm using:

```
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD($w0rdf1sh) WHERE user='tate256';
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Well what steps are you following? Simply putting it in won't work. If I remember correctly its a process and that code.

Comment: Ah. Do you remember the process of how to do it?

Comment: This is a bit more detailed and should be more easier to understand http://innovativethought.net/2007/05/17/resetting-your-forgotten-mysql-password/

Answer (score 122):

In your code, try enclosing password inside single quote. Alternatively, as per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html) of mysql, following should work -

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'jeffrey'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The last line is important or else your password change won't take effect unfortunately.

**EDIT:**

I ran a test in my local and it worked -

```
mysql>  set password for 'test' = PASSWORD('$w0rdf1sh');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Mine is version 5. You can use following command to determine your version -

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Comment: When I do that, it's returning syntax error near unexpected token ('

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? I picked up the above syntax from version 5.0 documentation. Did you try the command that I posted?

Comment: I believe I'm using a 4.0 version and yes I tried it

Comment: Command works well for me in MySQL Ver 14.14, ensure the password is wrapped in quotes and any quotes in the password are escaped.

Comment: ```error near unexpected token ('``` happens if you havent logged in to mysql but try to use the statements in the shell. Always log on mysql first with (f.e. root):  ```mysql -u root -p```

Comment: Strangely, even after flushing, still doesn't work for me :-( I'm using Mysql `5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

Answer (score 45):

### As of MySQL 5.7.6, use `ALTER USER`

Example:

```
ALTER USER 'username' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Because:

- `SET PASSWORD ... = PASSWORD('auth_string')` syntax is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 and will be removed in a future MySQL release.
- `SET PASSWORD ... = 'auth_string'` syntax is not deprecated, but `ALTER USER` is now the preferred statement for assigning passwords.

Comment: is this true even for interacting with MySQL via PHP?

Comment: @Anthony yes iff your MySQL version is >= 5.7.6

Comment: i'm new to MySQL. what does `ALTER USER ... IDENTIFIED BY ...` do exactly? how is that different from `UPDATE ... SET ...` or `INSERT INTO ...`?

Comment: `ALTER USER ... IDENTIFIED BY ...` is a SQL statement that configures user permissions for your database. `UPDATE` and `INSERT` have different functionalities, which like the names suggest, update records and insert records into tables in your database.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh `ALTER...` is for configuring user permission. that makes sense.

Comment: the genius who decided this just made virtually all tutorials and resource online out of date, and it is now a PITA to get started in mysql, I'm fuming rn.

Comment: Oh I see, the `ALTER` stuff passes through the password strength test plugin, and of course as usual in strenght checking, nobody heard of that https://www.xkcd.com/936/ and wrongly rejects very long passphrases. double fail, mysql.

Comment: gives error in mariaDb `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root' IDENTIFIED BY`

Comment: How about when using `--skip-grant-tables` to restore root access? I get this error. `ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded`

Comment: For me the syntax is: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Answer (score 14):

Note: you should login as root user

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your password');
```

Answer (score 7):

this is the updated answer for WAMP v3.0.6

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') 
WHERE user='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 3):

Before MySQL 5.7.6 this works from the command line:

```
mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('$w0rdf1sh');"
```

I don't have a mysql install to test on but I think in your case it would be

```
mysql -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('$w0rdf1sh') WHERE User='tate256';"
```

Answer (score 3):

As of MySQL 8.0.18
This works fine for me

```js
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'localhost' = 'userpassword';
```

Answer (score 2):

In windows 10, just exit out of current login and run this on command line

--> `mysqladmin -u root password “newpassword”`

where instead of root could be any user.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Got solution from [MYSQL webpage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

In MySQL run below queries:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New_Password';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query which worked for me.

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

After this you need to restart SQL server

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```

Earlier I was facing the same error,

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

But, now I can login using command `mysql -u root -p` and password `password`.

Answer (score -1):

Your login root should be `/usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf`. Then try following

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('$w0rdf1sh') WHERE user='tate256' AND Host='10.10.2.30';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Host is your mysql host.

Comment: Doesn't work. Returning syntax error near unexpected token ('