# how to change mysql password in WampServer Version 3.0.6 32bit

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I recently installed WampServer Version 3.0.6 32bit, i am trying to change the password of mysql. it shows the first error "No database selected". i selected the "MySql" database and try to create a password then it shows "Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'"

The command m using is "update user set password=password('abc@jkl') where user='root';

Comment: This can be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774739/change-mysql-user-password-using-command-line

Comment: Have you tried: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the MySQL console by selecting the menu shown above.
2. After clicking on the “MySQL console” following console window will be opened where default password is empty so we hit one enter key to continue without typing.

3.Now in order to change the default password we need to type following query in the MySQL console (in this example we are setting the password to– “foo“)

```
`SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('foo');`
```

4. In the older versions of the phpmyadmin we need to manually change the password in the phpmyadmin config file but in the current version we can skip this step.